# One of very many vs one of several

Tags: meaning

I need the exact definition and difference between "one of very many" and "one of several". They do not seem to express different amounts!

Comment: In both cases you end up with one thing.

Comment: My professor said there is a difference in their meaning and asked us for that. I searched but could not find anything!

Comment: And you can read the answers I received and learn their difference; seems you did not know :)))))))

Comment: Sure, let's go with the theory that I"m the one who did not know. You still end up with one thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They don't express *specific* amounts, but they do express *different* amounts.

Specifically, **one of many** would mean a single something inside a **much larger** group of somethings. For instance:

> Patty really wanted the job, but she was just **one of many** applicants for the position and nothing was guaranteed.

**One of several** would be a single something within a **much smaller** number of somethings, since several means around three or four in terms of amount. Such as:

> The teacher didn't like many students, but Patty was happy she was **one of several** whom he respected.

So categorically they're the same, but they mean very different things in usage.

Answer (score 0):

Several:

> more than two but not many.

Many:

> a large number of.

This means that

> One of very many

...expresses a higher quantity as in:

> Instagram is one of very many social networks acquired by Facebook